# Appending a row into existing CSV file in Pandas gives NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to add a row into the existing CSV file. 
This is the snapshot of the data stored in the CSV file.

[image]

And I extracted last row from another DF to append in the existing CSV file. This is the data I am trying to add in the CSV file.

[image]

Now, when I try to add the row into the file, it adds in a weird way. 
Snapshot of the code I am trying to add.

```
temp.to_csv('MarutiSEPFut.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

And after executing the above line, output of the CSV file is:

[image]

So, basically this is clearly not the desired output as all the values have been assigned into the first column and rest of the column values have been assigned as NaN.

Following is the code I am writing full_data into the CSV file.

```
full_data.to_csv("MarutiSEPFut.csv", sep='\t', index=False)
```

And to read from the CSV file:

```
from pandas import read_csv
import pandas as pd
csv_data = pd.read_csv("MarutiSEPFut.csv", sep='\t')
```

Any idea or suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your csv is separator tab, so add it to [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). If not specified, default separator is comma.

```
csv_data = pd.read_csv("MarutiSEPFut.csv", sep='\t')

temp.to_csv('MarutiSEPFut.csv', mode='a', header=False, sep='\t')
```